# ViewModelProvider no existe

Tags: android, viewmodel, jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

Estoy haciendo un curso de Android Jetpack en java, y estoy teniendo inconvenientes al usar ViewModel.
Al querer instanciar el viewModel con ViewModelProvider, no lo encuentra. y busque por todos lados a ver que podia ser y no encontre nada. ya no se si es mi compu, que esté poniendo algo mal en el gradle o las dependencias (probé todas las que pude sin resultados).

esto a continuacion es un template sin tocar. y ya desde el principio sale asi

```
package com.prueeba.viewmm.ui.main;


import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.prueeba.viewmm.R;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainViewModel mViewModel;

    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

}
```

asi se ve

[image: se ve en rojo que no existe]

[image: no lo encuentra]

este es el gradle con las dependecias

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prueeba.viewmm"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


}
```

y aca probé con un montón de variantes. sin el ktx, bajandole la version y nada...
y tiene instalados los SDK
Android API 33
Android API 32
Android API 31

No se que mas información les puede ser util. pero si tienen alguna idea por donde puede ir el problema. me ayudarian un montón!

muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Fernando, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes e ingreses el código como texto.

Comment: Ahi lo cambié gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar la clase `ViewModelProvider`:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
```

Debes agregar las siguientes dependencias en tu archivo `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1"
```

Es importante verificar que no tengas activado el "modo offline" para que puedas descargar las dependencias correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: funcionó con esa! a pesar de que sigue apareciendo como que no existe. pero siguiendo adelante con el codigo funciona!
cosa rara! gracias!!!

Comment: Si, obtuviste la dependencia y muestra que no existe, es solo sincronización, lo importante es que ya tienes la dependencia en tu proyecto, saludos.